# Show only complete lines at the top of sublime text's text area

Tags: sublimetext

When the text in sublime text scrolls, it shows me fractions of lines as the first line.

Is there a way to tell ST to always show full lines at the top which I'd prefer a lot.

This is the behaviour that I am seeing currently:

[image]

Comment: I did a google search with some variations but could not find an answer to this

Comment: I am working from linux to a windows box over rdp. Maybe that translates the amount differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's possible by playing with padding settings in your `User/Preferences.sublime-settings` file:

```
// Additional spacing at the top of each line, in pixels
"line_padding_top": 0,

// Additional spacing at the bottom of each line, in pixels
"line_padding_bottom": 0,
```

I think this is connected to your question about scrolling tabs with mouse. It may happen that ST receives floating point numbers. As I know - there is no way to make ST show full height first line. It also depends on the height of the buffer, when you scroll down to the end of the file, it will show full height last line and that may shift your top line

Comment: After trying out agaon I can confirm that the reason is the last line, the first line is alsways shown crippled, even if I am working on it, ST seems to alwas adjust to the last line. Very disturbing, probably a bug.

Comment: These little annoyances make me hope for a real open source editor where I can fix such stuff myself. Probably atom when it is done